# java doubling characters/tripling characters

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java program that will print letters twice; all other characters, such as spaces, numbers, and punctuation marks, are to be left alone, except for "!" which should be tripled. My program only doubles all characters so I'm not too sure what to do now as I am very new to Java.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a line of text.");
    String myStr = scan.nextLine();
    if (myStr.length()>0){
        String answer = "";
        for(int j=0; j<myStr.length(); j++){
            char ch = myStr.charAt(j);
            answer = answer + ch + ch;
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string longer than 0 characters");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simply** you can do it like this: **Use** regex, no need to any kind of **loop**.

**Just** Edit this line:

```
String answer = myStr.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha}|(!))", "$1$1$2");
```

**Usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a line of text.");
    String myStr = scan.nextLine();
    if (myStr.length()>0){
        String answer = myStr.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha}|(!))", "$1$1$2");
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string longer than 0 characters");
    }
}
```

**And the result:** *It is just what you want.*

```
Input: abc234&@!ff
Output: aabbcc234&@!!!ffff
```

Comment: Why it can be expensive than `for` loop

Comment: `except for "!" which should be tripled`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, using each line as `IntStream`, since char values are just integers;

```
String myStr = scan.nextLine().chars()
    .flatMap(ch -> {
        if (ch == '!') {
            return IntStream.of(ch, ch, ch);
        } else if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')) {
            return IntStream.of(ch, ch);
        }
        return IntStream.of(ch);
    })
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
```

It works great, and so much fun to work with Java streams

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String str = "abc!123";             
for(int x=0; x<str.length(); x++)
    if(str.substring(x, x+1).matches("[a-zA-Z+]"))    //if is alphabet
        System.out.print(str.substring(x, x+1) + str.substring(x, x+1));
    else if (str.substring(x, x+1).equals("!"))
        System.out.print("!!!");
    else    
        System.out.print(str.substring(x, x+1));
```

A rather straight forward approach which works accordingly to what you currently is doing. check whether a character is alphabet, print twice. If it is `!`, print 3 times. Else print the respective character once.

**Input:**

```
abc!123
```

**Output:**

```
aabbcc!!!123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();

    doubleStr(str);
}
public static void doubleStr(String s)
{
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();
    for(char a: array)
    {
        if(a>='0' && a<='9')
        {
            System.out.print(a);
        }else if(a=='!')
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(a);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(a);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Result
Original:  abc ! 9
aabbcc  !!!  9

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop of the characters will do it. Assuming you might want the result for other than simple printing, a transformation method returning the result would be better. That will also allow unit testing, if needed.

```
private static String transform(CharSequence input) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        buf.append(ch);
        if (ch == '!')
            buf.append(ch).append(ch);
        else if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            buf.append(ch);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Test**

```
System.out.println(transform("abc234&@!ff"));
System.out.println(transform("He said: \"You can't do that!\""));
```

**Output** from [Ideone](https://ideone.com/72moYu)

```
aabbcc234&@!!!ffff
HHee ssaaiidd: "YYoouu ccaann'tt ddoo tthhaatt!!!"
```